# AtomicInteger misbehavior

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I have an exercise: given a matrix of AtomicIntegers (initialized to 0), I have to run a thread for each rows, and a thread for each column, on the rows I subtract 1, on the columns I add 1, so at the end the matrix should remain as it was. The problem is that the matrix change! Here is the code:
The object takes the matrix, a boolean which will tell him to operate on columns or rows, and the index of the column/row where it must operate.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class FifthExerciseSafe implements Runnable{
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean onRows;//tells if the object operates on the rows or on the columns
    private AtomicInteger[][] matrix;
    private int index;

public FifthExerciseSafe(AtomicInteger[][] matrix, boolean onRows, int index){
    this.matrix = matrix;
    this.onRows = onRows;
    this.index = index;
}

public void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public boolean isOnRows() {
    return onRows;
}

public void setOnRows(boolean onRows) {
    this.onRows = onRows;
}

public AtomicInteger[][] getMatrix() {
    return matrix;
}

public void setMatrix(AtomicInteger[][] matrix) {
    this.matrix = matrix;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (this.onRows){
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix[index].length; i++){
            matrix[index][i].decrementAndGet();
        }
    } else {            
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            matrix[i][index].incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}//run

public static void main(String args[]){
    AtomicInteger[][] m = new AtomicInteger[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m.length; j++){
            m[i][j]= new AtomicInteger(0);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){//I create 6 objects, 3 for columns and 3 for rows
        FifthExerciseSafe fes1 = new FifthExerciseSafe(m, true, i);
        FifthExerciseSafe fes2 = new FifthExerciseSafe(m, false, i);
        fes1.start();
        fes2.start();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m.length; j++){
            System.out.print(m[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }
}//main
}
```

The output should be:
    000000
but sometimes it is:
-100-100-1-10

It only happens on a netbook with an Intel Atom, on a desktop with a Core Duo I haven't seen  it yet, but I'm wondering if it could happen there too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have started the threads, but you never wait for them to finish before going on to print out the matrix. You need to use `Thread.join` for each started thread, which will block until the thread is done. Only then will it be safe to print out the results. For example, introduce an `ArrayList` into which you `add` all the instances of `Thread` you start, and then have a separate `for` loop that invokes `join` on each instance.